# Simple XML - Dealing With Colons In Nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to read an RSS feed from Flickr but it has some nodes which are not readable by Simple XML (`media:thumbnail`, `flickr:profile`, and so on).

How do I get round this? My head hurts when I look at the documentation for the DOM. So I'd like to avoid it as I don't want to learn.

I'm trying to get the thumbnail by the way.

Comment: Related: [PHP library for parsing XML with a colons in tag names?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1575788/367456)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The solution is explained in [this nice article](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/10/20/simplexml-and-namespaces/). You need the `children()` method for accessing XML elements which contain a namespace. This code snippet is quoted from the article:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.sitepoint.com/recent.rdf'); 
foreach ($feed->item as $item) { 
    $ns_dc = $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'); 
    echo $ns_dc->date; 
}
```

Comment: If the XML had this tag <itunes:image href="myLink"> how then would you get the link?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau I propose to ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

With the latest version, you can now reference colon nodes with curly brackets.

```
$item->{'itunes:duration'}
```

Comment: The only answer that actually helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're dealing with a namespace? I think you need to use the ->children method.

```
$ns_dc = $item->children('http://namespace.org/');
```

Can you provide a snippet with the xml declaration?

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler method using PHP of accessing namespaced XML nodes **without** declaring a namespace is....

In order to get the value of `<su:authorEmail`> from the following source

```
<item>
  <title>My important article</title>
  <pubDate>Mon, 29 Feb 2017 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
  <link>https://myxmlsource.com/32984</link>
  <guid>https://myxmlsource.com/32984</guid>
  <author>Blogs, Jo</author>
  <su:departments>
    <su:department>Human Affairs</su:department>
  </su:departments>
  <su:authorHash>4f329b923419b3cb2c654d615e22588c</su:authorHash>
  <su:authorEmail>hIwW14tLc+4l/oo7agmRrcjwe531u+mO/3IG3xe5jMg=</su:authorEmail>
  <dc:identifier>/32984/Download/0032984-11042.docx</dc:identifier>
  <dc:format>Journal article</dc:format>
  <dc:creator>Blogs, Jo</dc:creator>
  <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
</item>
```

Use the following code:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();

$rss->load('https://myxmlsource.com/rss/xml');

$nodes = $rss->getElementsByTagName('item');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $author = $node->getElementsByTagName('author')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $authorHash = $node->getElementsByTagName('authorHash')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $department = $node->getElementsByTagName('department')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $email = $node->getElementsByTagName('authorEmail')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. You reference a function but then don't show the `decryptEmail` function

Comment: thanks @Micha - I've removed the reference