# How to get the whole XML elements of a particular namespace with their tags?

Tags: php, xml-namespaces, xml-parsing

I cannot find a specific question like this so I'm posting. Hopefully, this will be of general use.

I have a file that includes XML tags of "`<w:t> data data.....</w:t>`". There is a lot of other stuff too. I need to capture everything within (and including) the `<w:t></w:t>` tags.

I'd appreciate hearing suggestions on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance..

David

Comment: You should use a real XML-parser (like DOM or such), instead of hacks

Comment: There are quite a few questions on SO about parsing XML files with PHP, and capturing the data therein. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+xml+parsing

Comment: Thanks guys. This is a one time conversion from a (350page) MSWord document, that I want to end up as an xml or mysql file.

Comment: possible duplicate ? [xml parsing with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337510/xml-parsing-with-php/4337871)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using DomXml is preferred option since it does not restrict you to searching for other tags/data.

But using regular expressions makes far less code so I would go for preg_match_all if those tags are only thing you need.

```
$string = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <w:t>some data...</w:t>
    <not-captured>data data</not-captured>
    <w:t>more data...</w:t>
</root>
</xml>';

preg_match_all('/<w\:t>.*<\/w\:t>/is', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

response:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "<w:t>some data...</w:t>"
    [1]=>
    string(23) "<w:t>more data...</w:t>"
  }
}
```

Edit: /is modifier added to regex

Comment: Thank you Ivan... I got it.. I can't post the script here as I'm a noob, but it is along the lines of your code..

Comment: You won’t get that result as the `*` is greedy.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, I would include an 's' in lower-case after the i in the end to take care of line breaks.

Good point by Mr. Gumbo below. Yes do also add a 'U' in upper-case after the 's' to make the expression less greedy otherwise it won't work as expected

e.g.

preg_match_all('/.*<\/w\:t>/isU', $string, $matches);

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that: . represents any character except new line characters. /s modifier suppresses that behavior and . traps new lines

Comment: Nice one with the regex though

Comment: I have a lot to learn, thank you all for chipping in. Now I have my - very rough - but compliant XML file, I have to figure out how to assign sub-tags to specific elements. The elements are in greek so it isn't easy..

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a XML DOM parser like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml):

```
$string = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:w="http://example.com/">
    <w:t>some data...</w:t>
    <not-captured>data data</not-captured>
    <w:t>more data...</w:t>
</root>';
$doc = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach ($doc->xpath('//w:t') as $elem) {
    var_dump($elem->asXML());
}
```

If you do not specify the namespace for *w* in your XML document, use [SimpleXMLElement::registerXPathNamespace](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace):

```
$doc->registerXPathNamespace('w', 'http://example.com/');
```