# How do I access sub tags in the flickr RSS feed using php?

Tags: php, flickr

I am pulling info from my flickr RSS feed and have hit a road bump. Things like the image url and title 
are in simple `<Title>` and `<Link>` tags. And I get them like this

```
if($item['title'] !== "") 
   $title = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($item['title']));
else 
   $title = $settings['default_title'];

$url = $item['link'];
```

But in the flickr RSS feed tags and descriptions are outputted like this

```
<media:category scheme="urn:flickr:tags">coffee coding</media:category>
<media:description type="html"> <p>even coffee isn't helping with coding today<br /> :(</p> </media:description>
```

How do I access these tags? I have tried

```
$tag = $item['media_category'];
$desc = $item['media_description'];
```

And

```
$tag = $item['media:category'];
$desc = $item['media:description'];
```

Neither seem to work?

Comment: How are you loading the RSS?  SimpleXML? DOMDocument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml) you might also want to look at [this](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/688#Heading3)

Answer (score 1):

To access the XML namespace elements using SimpleXML, try this:

```
// Load namespaces
$namespaces = $item->getNamespaces(TRUE);

// Get media namespace
$media = $entry->children($namespaces['media']);
echo $media->category;
echo $media->description;
```

[Some more info in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575788/php-library-for-parsing-xml-with-a-colons-in-tag-names)