# Get the data from api.hostip.info

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml

I am trying to get information about an IP address from api.hostip.info but the following code  returns the current XML version;

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://api.hostip.info/?ip=12.215.42.19';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($xml);
```

How can I return the data from the URL?

Comment: Na. I want to get the information from api.hostip.info so I can match `countryAbbrev` with my function I have. `$xml = htmlentities($xml);` did by the way return many new lines with no text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the XML contains colons (namespace), you have to do it a bit differently [and use this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575788/php-library-for-parsing-xml-with-a-colons-in-tag-names) to access the namespace:

```
var_dump($xml->children('gml', true)->featureMember->children()->Hostip);

/*
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (5) {
      ["ip"]=>
      string(12) "12.215.42.19"
      ["countryName"]=>
      string(13) "UNITED STATES"
      ["countryAbbrev"]=>
      string(2) "US"
      ["comment"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
      }
      ["ipLocation"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) {
      }
    }
*/
```

..should give you exactly what you want:

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot :)