# Extract <im:rating> from apple feeds

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How can   from the below xml . I am using php SimpleXmlElement to parse the entire xml.I am getting all the details other than this element .

```
<feed xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="en">
<id>
    https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=977/sortBy=mostRecent/xml
</id>
<title>iTunes Store: Customer Reviews</title>
<updated>2013-11-19T05:55:27-07:00</updated>
<entry>
<updated>2013-11-14T05:27:00-07:00</updated>
<id>895482313</id>
<title>Still </title>
<content type="text">
The app continues to .
</content>
<im:contentType term="Application" label="Application"/>
<im:voteSum>0</im:voteSum>
<im:voteCount>0</im:voteCount>
<im:rating>4</im:rating>
<im:version>3.1</im:version>
<author>
<name>LIMHP2010</name>
<uri>https://itunes.apple.com/us/reviews/id15104323</uri>
</author>
<link rel="related" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/review?id=722846977&type=Purple%20Software"/>
<content type="html">
<table border="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td> <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr valign="top" align="left"> <td width="100%"> <b><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tricycle-magazine/id722846977?mt=8&uo=2">Still Crashing during updating</a></b><br/> <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular"> </font> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular"><br/>On iPhone 5s, iOS 7.0.3 - <br/><br/>Customer service was fantastic at fixing the problem of zooming into much. The problem of crashing while attempting to update purchases continues.<br/><br/>The app continues to be essentially useless.</font><br/> </td> </tr> </table>
</content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use DOMXpath::evaluate(). SimpleXml hides functions from you. In this case I think your problem are namespaces. PHP automatically registers the namespaces of the current context (the second argument of `query()/evaluate()`), you don't really want that, it can interfere with your own namespace definition. The third argument of `query()/evaluate()` disables the automatic registration.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// register the namespaces you would like to use with own prefixes
$xpath->registerNamespace('itunes', 'http://itunes.apple.com/rss');
$xpath->registerNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

var_dump(
  'Entries: '.$xpath->evaluate('count(//atom:entry)', NULL, FALSE)
);
// fetch the list of entry nodes
$entries = $xpath->evaluate('//atom:entry', NULL, FALSE);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  // fetch values from the entry node children
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:title)', $entry, FALSE),
    $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:content)', $entry, FALSE),
    $xpath->evaluate('string(itunes:contentType/@label)', $entry, FALSE),
    $xpath->evaluate('string(itunes:version)', $entry, FALSE),
    $xpath->evaluate('number(itunes:rating)', $entry, FALSE)
  );
}
```

Unlike query(), evaluate() can return scalar values, too.

```
string(10) "Entries: 1"
string(6) "Still "
string(24) "
The app continues to .
"
string(11) "Application"
string(3) "3.1"
float(4)
```

Comment: this works great for me. Thank you. One more question how to get the author detail from this xml

Comment: got it. This will return the author name $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:author/atom:name)', $entry);

Comment: Add the third parameter, if you don't the atomatic namespace registration is active. This has a perfomance impact, but more important an xmlns:atom or xmlns:itunes attribute on the $entry context node would override your own namespace definition. This can result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: cool . By adding third parameter on my script which is running on  centos5 + php 5.2.7 is not working properly. After removing it starts working :)

Comment: It was added in PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: @ThW hi, can you please tell me If the feed data can be saved in personal db to reuse the same. I tried going through terms & conditions of iTunes, but could not find any

Comment: Sorry no, I am not a lawyer and SO is definitely not the place to ask legal questions.

Comment: Please, explain to me What is the meaning of  `<im:voteSum>0</im:voteSum>
<im:voteCount>0</im:voteCount>`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this
`$review->children('im', true)->rating` using `SimpleXMLElement()`

Answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696743/2976631).