# get xml elemnts data with php

Tags: php, xml

I get xml object using curl.

But I can not seem to enter xml elements data.

I tried using:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
$final_xml = $sxe->asXML();
echo  $final_xml ->  Answer -> Status;
```

With that example I got nothing.

OR

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($sxe);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json);
```

With that example I got an array of the xml as a long string and each position in the array was different note in the xml string.

This is the xml output I get, that I want to retrieve data from:
how can I retrieve data from this xml or change it to JSON and then retrieve data?

Thanx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
    <ns7:GetStopMonitoringServiceResponse xmlns:ns3="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns:ns4="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/acsb" xmlns:ns5="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/ifopt" xmlns:ns6="http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0" xmlns:ns7="http://new.webservice.namespace">
   <Answer>
      <ns3:ResponseTimestamp>2014-12-04T11:11:55.585+02:00</ns3:ResponseTimestamp>
      <ns3:ProducerRef>ISR Siri Server (141.10)</ns3:ProducerRef>
      <ns3:ResponseMessageIdentifier>89061165</ns3:ResponseMessageIdentifier>
      <ns3:RequestMessageRef>000234:1351677777:4684</ns3:RequestMessageRef>
      <ns3:Status>true</ns3:Status>
      <ns3:StopMonitoringDelivery version="IL2.7">
          <ns3:ResponseTimestamp>2014-12-04T11:11:55.585+02:00</ns3:ResponseTimestamp>
          <ns3:RequestMessageRef>0</ns3:RequestMessageRef>
          <ns3:Status>true</ns3:Status>
          <ns3:MonitoredStopVisit>
               <ns3:RecordedAtTime>2014-12-04T11:11:00.000+02:00</ns3:RecordedAtTime>
               <ns3:ItemIdentifier>1448001046</ns3:ItemIdentifier>
               <ns3:MonitoringRef>40262</ns3:MonitoringRef>
               <ns3:MonitoredVehicleJourney>
                    <ns3:LineRef>4687</ns3:LineRef>
                    <ns3:DirectionRef>3</ns3:DirectionRef>
                    <ns3:PublishedLineName>12</ns3:PublishedLineName>
                    <ns3:OperatorRef>3</ns3:OperatorRef>
                    <ns3:DestinationRef>40110</ns3:DestinationRef>
                    <ns3:OriginAimedDepartureTime>2014-12-04T10:45:00.000+02:00</ns3:OriginAimedDepartureTime>
                    <ns3:VehicleLocation>
                         <ns3:Longitude>34.94065475463867</ns3:Longitude>
                         <ns3:Latitude>32.428466796875</ns3:Latitude>
                    </ns3:VehicleLocation>
                    <ns3:MonitoredCall>
                         <ns3:StopPointRef>40262</ns3:StopPointRef>
                         <ns3:ExpectedArrivalTime>2014-12-04T11:12:00.000+02:00</ns3:ExpectedArrivalTime>
                    </ns3:MonitoredCall>
               </ns3:MonitoredVehicleJourney>
          </ns3:MonitoredStopVisit>
      </ns3:StopMonitoringDelivery>
    </Answer>
</ns7:GetStopMonitoringServiceResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575788/php-library-for-parsing-xml-with-a-colons-in-tag-names

Comment: hi i tried this and still nothing what i'm doing wrong? itried the syntax  echo $result->children('S', true)->Envelope->children()->Body->children('ns7' , true)->GetStopMonitoringServiceResponse->children()->Answer->children('ns3' , true)->Status ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this test code:

```
<pre><?php

$entries = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$namespaces = $entries->getNamespaces(true);

var_dump($namespaces);

$ns3s = $entries->children($namespaces['S'])
            ->Body
            ->children($namespaces['ns7'])
            ->GetStopMonitoringServiceResponse
            ->children()
            ->Answer
            ->children($namespaces['ns3']);

var_dump($ns3s);
```

Comment: thanx! that solved my problem. i used "simplexml_load_string" instead of "simplexml_load_file" and it worked