# Can't read attribute value of xml <media:content> tags

Tags: php, xml, dom, rss

I'm trying to read the *media:content* **url**, without success. How to do it?

> XML

```
<rss>
<item>
      <media:content url="pizza.jpg">
        <media:text>Pizza</media:text>
      </media:content>
</item>
<item>
      <media:content url="pasta.jpg">
        <media:text>Pasta</media:text>
      </media:content>
</item>
</rss>
```

> PHP

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('file.xml');
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    $item_img=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('media:content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
    echo $item_img
}
```

Comment: Try SimpleXML.

$xml = new SimpleXML('<xml></xml>');
$attributes = $xml->item->attributes();

Comment: @WojtekB is a remote xml file.

Comment: Here you find the [the code to do it with SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575788/php-library-for-parsing-xml-with-a-colons-in-tag-names).

Comment: You can use file_get_content() to load remote file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the worst of solutions:

> PHP

```
$xmlText= file_get_contents('file.xml');
$xmlText=str_replace('<media:', '<media', $xmlText);
$xmlText=str_replace('</media:', '</media', $xmlText);
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc-> loadXML($xmlText);
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    $item_img=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('mediacontent')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
    echo $item_img
}
```