# PHP Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when getting RSS

Tags: php, foreach, rss

I seem to be having trouble accessing a portion of an RSS feed. I have read this article: [Accessing date as XML node in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805378/accessing-date-as-xml-node-in-php) and [Problem getting author from a wordpress RSS feed using SimpleXmlElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307567/problem-getting-author-from-a-wordpress-rss-feed-using-simplexmlelement) article but I still cannot seem to get this to work.

```
<item>
  <title>This is the title</title>
  <dc:creator>!an (@myHandle)</dc:creator>
  <description><![CDATA[<p class="TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text"  lang="en">What is this tweeet</p>]]></description>
  <pubDate>Tue, 03 Jan 2017 22:01:54 +0000</pubDate>
  <guid>1234567</guid>
  <link>1234567</link>
  <twitter:source/>
  <twitter:place/>
</item>
```

here is the portion of the rss I am getting. Here is the full RSS: https://twitrss.me/twitter_search_to_rss/?term=test+this+feed

I am trying to access this with PHP code like so:

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
 $feed->load('https://twitrss.me/twitter_search_to_rss/?term=test+this+feed');

foreach ($feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0) as $item) {
  $ns_dc = $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
  echo $ns_dc->creator;
}
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I have tried changing it to:

```
$feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)
```

but then nothing outputs.

I also tried:

```
$feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')
```

but then get the error:

> Call to undefined method DOMElement::children()

## Question

Please can someone tell me, using PHP how to access the dc:creator tag and assign that value to a variable?

## Edit

```
      $i = 1;
  foreach ($feed->channel as $row) {
    echo $i;
    
      foreach ($row->children() as $key => $val) {
          if ($key == "item") {
            if ($i == 1) {
              $ns_dc = $val->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
              echo $ns_dc->creator;
              }
          }
          
      }
      
    $i = $i + 1;
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you should just be using `$feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')` in your for each.

Comment: Please see bottom of answer. Tried it but got the error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::children()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with XML content, I found it easier to use SimpleXML instead of DOMDocument. Since each `<item>` is in the same block as `channel` you can do a foreach looking for a key of `item`.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('https://twitrss.me/twitter_search_to_rss/?term=test+this+feed');

foreach ($feed->channel as $row) {
    foreach ($row->children() as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == "item") {
            $ns_dc = $val->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
            echo $ns_dc->creator;
        }
    }
}
```

This code outputs the "creator" string you expect.

Comment: Nope. I solved it. I just wanted the most recent. Thank you.. I have accepted the answer and +1. Thanks dude for the quick response.