# SimpleXML parse get past colon PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, simplexml

Hi I want to access the value in an XML feed:

```
<entry>
<ilink:operation>store</ilink:operation>
<ilink:type>ondemand</ilink:type>
<id>736</id>
<updated>2012-03-13T11:27:32Z</updated>
<content type="application/xml">
   <media:content>
      <ilink:parent_id>8132</ilink:parent_id>
      <ilink:availability_start>2012-01-06T00:00:00Z</ilink:availability_start>
      <ilink:availability_end>2012-02-03T00:00:00Z</ilink:availability_end>
      <ilink:duration>PT0S</ilink:duration>
   </media:content>
</content>
```

But the colons are getting in the way. How do I access that? Here's my code:

```
$pictureBoxXMLFeed = simplexml_load_file('https://www.picturebox.tv/xml/feeds/FindAnyFilm/FindAnyFilm.xml');

foreach($pictureBoxXMLFeed->entry as $value){

    $hey = ($value->children('content')->children('media', true)->content->children('ilink', true)->parent_id);
    echo $hey;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

But I just get a list of errors. Please can someone help me get to it?

Comment: You can do better than "a list of errors".

Comment: Ok I get - Warning: main(): Node no longer exists in /vagrant/LucidSite/PictureBox/picturebox/trunk/services/dynamicreel.php on line 24 Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /vagrant/LucidSite/PictureBox/picturebox/trunk/services/dynamicreel.php on line 24

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple XML - Dealing With Colons In Nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186107/simple-xml-dealing-with-colons-in-nodes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML as you posted it is syntactically incorrect.  There's no closing `</entry>` tag and there are no namespace definitions in it.  This caused many a warning when attempting to come up with an answer.

Once I fixed those issues in the XML I used the following to get what you seem to be looking for:

```
foreach($pictureBoxXMLFeed->xpath('//content') as $content){
    $hey = ($content->children('media', true)->content->children('ilink', true)->parent_id);
    echo $hey;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```