# Can't find/access tags in xml object

Tags: php, xml

How to acces `geo:lat` and `geo:long` in this feed? Can't see it in the var_dump.

Basically I know how to use the obj returned by `simplexml_load_file`, however I can't find the geo tags.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.livep2000.nl/');

//var_dump($feed);
foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item) {
  $title       = (string) $item->title;
  $description = (string) $item->description;
  $pubDate = (string) $item->pubDate;
  $geo = (string) $item->geo:lat;

  print_r($item);
}
```

EDIT: updated code

Comment: can you show you have currently written to try to get the tags you want? Also can you include representative sample of the XML in your question?

Comment: just updated the code. and for the XML just load http://feeds.livep2000.nl/ in your browser

Comment: Answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186107/simple-xml-dealing-with-colons-in-nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this simple test:

```
<?php

$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.livep2000.nl');

echo "<pre>".print_r($feed,true)."</pre>";


?>
```

The reason why it doesn't show de geo tags it's because they don't exist in the $feed var.

Sample output fo the code:

```
[item] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [link] => http://monitor.livep2000.nl?SPI=1311111908030208
                        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [pubDate] => Mon, 11 Nov 2013 19:08:03 +0100
                        [guid] => 1311111908030208
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [link] => http://monitor.livep2000.nl?SPI=1311111908010223
                        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [pubDate] => Mon, 11 Nov 2013 19:08:01 +0100
                        [guid] => 1311111908010223
                    )
```

Now you can access the Lat and Long values in this way:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.livep2000.nl');

foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item) {
  $ns_dc = $item->children('http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#');
  echo "Lat: ".$ns_dc->lat."    |  Long: ".$ns_dc->long."</br>";
}
```

And the proper output of the script:

```
Lat: 52.5123727 | Long: 4.9528409
Lat: 51.52939 | Long: 5.0269987
Lat: 52.4189359 | Long: 4.8860944
Lat: 52.5146807 | Long: 4.7027031
```

Comment: but loading the feed in the browser does show these tags, how come?

Comment: I'm working in a proper method to access those tags...just wait ;)