# PHP: getting images from a Wordpress feed when they are attached as multimedia

Tags: php, wordpress, image, rss, feed

I have a rss feed with this structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0"
        xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
        xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
        >
    <channel>
        <title>Title</title>
        <atom:link href="url" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <link>url</link>
        <description>desc</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Tue, 21 Oct 2014 12:50:06 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <language>en-EN</language>
            <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
            <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
        <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.8.1</generator>
        <item>
            <title>Hello</title>
            <link>helloUrl/</link>
            <comments>comments</comments>
            <pubDate>Tue, 21 Oct 2014 12:44:18 +0000</pubDate>
            <dc:creator><![CDATA[admin]]></dc:creator>
            <category><![CDATA[General]]></category>       
            <guid isPermaLink="false">permalink</guid>
            <description><![CDATA[this is a description]]></description>
        <media:content url="IMAGEurl" medium="image" />

<content:encoded><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=</a><p><a href="imageURL" rel="lightbox[68]"><img class="wp-image-67 alignleft" alt="alt" src="imageURL" width="164" height="164" /></a> 
<p>&nbsp;</p><object data="http://www.youtube.com/v/?version=3&rel=0&fs=1&showinfo=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="604" height="370">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/?version=3&rel=0&fs=1&showinfo=0"></param>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
</object>
<p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi//default.jpg" width="130" height="97" border=0></a></p>
<p><a class="a2a_dd a2a_target addtoany_share_save" href="http://www.addtoany.com/share_save#url=" id="wpa2a_2"><img src="/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/share_save_171_16.png" width="171" height="16" alt="Share"/></a></p>]]></content:encoded>
<wfw:commentRss>feedURL</wfw:commentRss>
<slash:comments>0</slash:comments>


            </item>
            .
            .
```

In order to get the information contained, this is my php:

```
<?php
  $url ="myrss.rss";
  $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
  if($rss)
  {
      echo '<h1>'.$rss->channel->title.'</h1>';
      echo '<li>'.$rss->channel->pubDate.'</li>';
      $items = $rss->channel->item;
      foreach($items as $item)
      {

          $title = $item->title;
          $link = $item->link;
          $published_on = $item->pubDate;
          $description = $item->description;
          echo '<h3><a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a></h3>';
          echo '<span>('.$published_on.')</span>';
          echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';

          $ns_media = $item->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
          echo $ns_media->content; 
      }
  }
```

And everything is being printed ok but for the image url. I need the image url so I can build a webpage with images and text coming from the rss feed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

SOLVED:

Just in case somebody need it:

Don't use simplexml_load_file

Use

```
  $rss = file_get_contents('myrss.xml');
  $rss = str_replace('<media:', '<', $rss);
```

Comment: can you show me the content of media node xml?

Comment: Please, post your solution as an Answer below.

Comment: I think the real issue has to do with [Simple XML - Dealing With Colons In Nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1186107/1287812)

Comment: @MiguelMas your method is a hack--do you want to know the correct way to deal with `media:` nodes in SimpleXML?