# SimpleXml Get Attribute Value

Tags: php

I am trying to get recent posts from my blog's rss and print them through php, All I have done has worked fine but I am unable to get image thumbnail from the XML file. It is stored in an attribute.

My xml output is:

```
<item><title>Stackoverflow inspired movies list</title><link>http://www.example.com/2015/03/movies-list.html</link><author>(Ididntknewit)</author><media:thumbnail xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' url='http://the.url.com/image.png' height='72' width='72'/><thr:total>0</thr:total></item>
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');

$rss =simplexml_load_file($requestURL);
?>
<?php
echo '<ul>';
foreach($rss->channel->item as $post){
    echo '<li>';
    $max = $post->media:thumbnail['url'];
    echo $max;
    echo '<a href="'.$post->link.'">'.$post->title.'</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

How can I get the thumbnail URL.

Comment: Where have you seen this syntax - `$post->media:thumbnail['url']` ?

Comment: @nevvermind I don't know

Comment: Then why did you used it? Have you searched how to get an attribute from a SimpleXml element?

Comment: yupp! Can;t figure out still, you know how ? :(

Comment: Why, of course! I just go to google and search for it.

Comment: I am asking about answert to the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you wanted. Dude, just search in google for this one, don't be ridiculous. Or check out the "Related" section on the right side of this web page.  After you find out, delete this question.

Comment: THANKS for Your 'KIND' Suggestion.

Comment: I *am* kind! I'm teaching you how to search! That's better than giving you the answers, believe me. You'll be giving _yourself_ answers shortly if you learn to use google.

Comment: You have got the answer, if you still want to learn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186107/simple-xml-dealing-with-colons-in-nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that SimpleXML won't parse media:thumbnail. I wrote a quick solution for you, but I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way of doing this:

```php
header('Content-Type: text/html');

$rss = simplexml_load_string(
    // replace media:thumbnail with mediathumbnail
    str_replace(
        'media:thumbnail',
        'mediathumbnail',
        file_get_contents($requestURL)
    )
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($rss->channel->item as $post)
{
    echo '<li>';
    // getting mediathumbnail attributes
    $attributes = $post->mediathumbnail->attributes();
    // this is the thumbnail url
    $max = $attributes->url;
    echo $max;
    echo '<a href="'.$post->link.'">'.$post->title.'</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Hope I helped. :)

Comment: It's the right answer, but you haven't helped him. You gave him a fish, but the guy needs to learn _to_ fish.

Comment: you are welcome :)
@nevvermind I know, but I try to answers questions, I can't learn things for him. :)