# make limit of content when getting data from xml to php

Tags: php, xml, limit, fetch

Hello guys i'm getting data from xml to php and i want to make limit. for example get only 10 post down is a examples of my xml file and php code

This is xml file from where i'm getting data : 
http://myscandal.ge/sitemap.xml

And there is a php code, so i'm getting data from xml file :

http://mymus.ge/example.txt

Comment: You should list your code **in the question body** if you are interested in answers.  Links can change over time, making the question much less relevant in the future, and many people avoid links to unknown websites for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a counter inside your foreach loop and break when it reaches the limit you want. Something like

```
$countrer = 0;
foreach(..){ 
   // your code here
  $counter++; 
  if($counter == X) break;
}
```

Where X the number of results you want.

Comment: thanks its working fine!!! sorry i cant give you rep, i havent enough rep :( thanks mate its working

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer since it helped you.

Comment: also i have another question how to get image url from here? http://myscandal.ge/index.xml

there is <media:thumbnail url=""> and i cant get

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186107/simple-xml-dealing-with-colons-in-nodes

Comment: already seen but not working, now you know my examples and can u help me?

Comment: Do you have the xml? I don't see any <media> in the one in your question