# Read colon tags values XML PHP

Tags: php, xml

I've already read those topics:
[PHP library for parsing XML with a colons in tag names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575788/php-library-for-parsing-xml-with-a-colons-in-tag-names) and
[Simple XML - Dealing With Colons In Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186107/simple-xml-dealing-with-colons-in-nodes) but i coundt implement those solutions.

```
<item>
<title> TITLE </title>
<itunes:author> AUTHOR </itunes:author>
<description> TEST </description>
<itunes:subtitle> TEST </itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary> TEST </itunes:summary>
<itunes:image href="yoyoyoyo.jpg"/>
<pubDate> YESTERDAY </pubDate>
<itunes:block>no</itunes:block>
<itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:duration>99:99:99</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>key, words</itunes:keywords>
</item>
```

I want to get only itunes:duration and itunes:image. Here is my code:

```
$result = simplexml_load_file("http://blablabla.com/feed.xml");

$items = $result->xpath("//item");

foreach ($items as $item) {

    echo $item->title;
    echo $item->pubDate;
}
```

I tried using `children()` method but when i try to `print_r` it it says that the node no longer exists.

Comment: According to w3c rules for [qualified names](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#ns-qualnames), a namespace prefix must be defined in root or ancestor element. Unless your post is a snippet, no where in your XML is `itunes` namespace defined such as: `xmlns:itunes="http://www.apple.com"`.

Comment: This is not mine XML, its from a website where im planning to crawl it. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `children()` on the `$item` element to get it's child-elements:

```
$str =<<< END
<item>
<title> TITLE </title>
<itunes:author> AUTHOR </itunes:author>
<description> TEST </description>
<itunes:subtitle> TEST </itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary> TEST </itunes:summary>
<itunes:image href="yoyoyoyo.jpg"/>
<pubDate> YESTERDAY </pubDate>
<itunes:block>no</itunes:block>
<itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:duration>99:99:99</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>key, words</itunes:keywords>
</item>
END;

$result = @simplexml_load_string($str);

$items = $result->xpath("//item");

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->title . "\n";
    echo $item->pubDate . "\n";
    echo $item->children()->{'itunes:duration'} . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
TITLE
YESTERDAY
99:99:99
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot Dekel. I must read more about xpath since i couldnt find this anywhere.

Comment: Sorry to correct but i tested your code (and mine after the change) and none of them worked. The 99:99:99 didnt showed on your code either, and i copy pasted it.

Comment: Ok i got it working by using $item->children()->duration instead. I dont know why it accepts duration but not itunes:duration. When i did print_r on the $item it showed the element as "duration" instead of ïtunes:duration"

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my alternative solution if Dekel's dont work for someone.

Using method `getNamespaces`

```
$result = simplexml_load_file("http://blablabla.com/feed.xml");

$items = $result->xpath("//item");

foreach ($items as $item) 
{

    $itunesSpace = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
    $nodes = $item->children($itunesSpace['itunes']);

    //TEST
    echo $nodes->subtitle

    //99:99:99
    echo $nodes->duration

    //If you want the image Href

    $imageAux = $nodes->image->attributes();
    //yoyoyoyo.jpg
    echo $imageAux['href'];
}
```