# how to read Dc:creator tag in xml?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, vbulletin

the rss feed export is:

```html
<item>
<title>◀️تنبلی گروهی چیست؟</title>
<link>
http://forum.mlmarketing.ir/showthread.php/241-◀️تنبلی-گروهی-چیست؟?goto=newpost
</link>
<pubDate>Wed, 08 Feb 2017 07:37:19 GMT</pubDate>
<description>
*✏️مهندس فرانسوی به نام رینگلمن که روی کارایی اسبها کار می کرد دریافت که قدرت حمل بار دو اسب با دو برابر قدرت حمل بار یک اسب برابر نیست. او این...
</description>
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<div><b><span style="font-family: IranSans">✏️مهندس فرانسوی به نام رینگلمن که روی کارایی اسبها کار می کرد دریافت که قدرت حمل بار دو اسب با دو برابر قدرت حمل بار یک اسب برابر نیست. او این مطالعه را به رفتار گروهی انسانها نیز تعمیم داد. نتایج جالب توجه بود. اگر دو نفر در یک تیم طناب کشی حاضر شوند هر یک تا 93% توان خود را به کار خواهند گرفت. اگر طناب کشی بین گروههای سه نفره انجام شود هر یک از اعضاء تیم 85% توان خود را به کار خواهد گرفت، این عدد در مورد یک تیم هشت نفره برای هر فرد تنها 49% خواهد بود!</span></b><br /> <br /> <b>✏️در روانشناسی اجتماعی ثابت شده است که کارایی گروهها و تیمهای کاری از جمع کارایی تک تک اعضاء گروه کمتر است. کاهش تلاش فرد در یک تیم ناشی از دیده نشدن است. در واقع افراد هنگامی حداکثر توان ذهنی و جسمی خود را به کار می گیرند که این تلاش به طور مشخص قابل سنجش و ارزیابی باشد. اگر صرف توان و تلاش یک فرد عضو یک تیم در عملکرد کلی گروه به طور مشخص قابل اندازه گیری نباشد، تنبلی کردن رفتار نرمال اعضاء گروه خواهد بود. به این پدیده تنبلی گروهی (Social Loafing) گفته می شود.</b><br /> <br /> <b>✏️وقتی افراد با هم کار می کنند کارایی کاهش می یابد و این خیلی غیر عادی نیست. این کاهش کارایی تا حدی است که عملکرد کلی تیم به طور کامل مختل نشود چون در شرایطی که تیم ببازد هیچ یک از افراد از عواقب آن ایمن نخواهد بود. افراد در تیم سطح تنبلی خود را طوری تنظیم می کنند که به طور مشخص بازنده بودن تیم به چشم نیاید.</b><br /> <br /> <b>✏️تنبلی گروهی پیامدهای جالب توجهی دارد. هیچ کس در یک گروه به تصور خود نمی خواهد پیامدهای منفی تصمیم گیریها و عملکرد گروهی را بپذیرد و مایل است(به ویژه زمانی که تیم باخته است) خود را پشت تصمیمات گروه پنهان کند(Diffusion of Responsibility). </b><br /> <br /> <b>✏️از طرفی معمولا ریسک پذیری گروه از یک فرد مشخص بیشتر است. چرا که همه می دانند در صورتی که کارها خوب پیش نرود پیامدهای های آن گریبانگیر یک فرد نخواهد بود(Risky Shift). این موضوع می تواند بسیار خطرناک باشد به ویژه در مورد تصمیم های بسیار خاص، مانند هنگامی که قرار است راجع به شلیک اولین موشک اتمی تصمیم گیری شود.</b><br /> <br /> <b>✏️ولی آیا رفتار تنبلی گروهی به مفهوم عدم کارایی تیمها است؟ پاسخ این سوال منفی است چرا که ما به جهت نیاز به تخصصهای متنوع در حوزه های مختلف و نیز آثار مثبت روانی همکاری بین افراد، الزام به تشکیل تیم داریم ولی جهت پرهیز از کاهش کارایی تیمی باید تا حد ممکن تیمهای کاری را در گروههای کوچکتر سازماندهی کنیم و به علاوه مکانیسم مشخصی برای اندازه گیری و ارزیابی عملکرد اعضاء تیم طراحی و اجراء کنیم.</b><br /> <br /> <b>✏️شاید مثل &quot;دیگی که برای من نجوشه، سر سگ توش بجوشه&quot; نمایانگر شاخصه فرهنگی ما ایرانیان در فعالیتهای گروهی است. ما رفتارهای فردی و اجتماعی خود را متناسب با سودهای به شدت شخصی و کوتاه مدت تنظیم می کنیم و سوی چشمانمان در تشخیص منافع بلند اجتماعی به شدت ضعیف است. ما به طور آشکاری در فعالیتهای گروهی ضعیف ظاهر می شویم چون مسئولیت پذیری، تعهد، حس تعلق و همبستگی اجتماعی در جامعه اکنون ما در سطح مطلوبی نیست.</b><br /> <br /> <b>*برگرفته از #کتاب The Art of Thinking Clearly</b><br /> <b><br /> <a href="http://forum.mlmarketing.ir/register.php" target="_blank">به خانواده ام ال مارکتینگ بپیوندید</a></b></div>
]]>
</content:encoded>
<category domain="http://forum.mlmarketing.ir/forumdisplay.php/128-روانشناسی">روانشناسی</category>
<dc:creator>Ali Mousavi</dc:creator>
<guid isPermaLink="true">
http://forum.mlmarketing.ir/showthread.php/241-◀️تنبلی-گروهی-چیست؟
</guid>
</item>
```

I can read title, description, link and category tags data by the codes below, how can i read the dc:creator tag's data? i wrote some codes as dc:creator, and dc for element chooser, but it not works

```html
<?php
echo '<div id="MTForumBlock">
<table id="lastpost">
        <tr class="MTForumfirst">
            <td class="MTForumtitle">عنوان</td>
            <td class="MTForumview">موضوع</td>
            <td class="MTForumview">نویسنده</td>
</tr>';
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://forum.mlmarketing.ir/external.php?type=RSS2', 'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA); 
$p_cnt = count($xml->channel->item);
if($p_cnt == "0"){
echo'<div align="center"><font color="#008080" face="Tahoma">انجمن خالیست !</font></div>';
} else {
for($i = 0; $i < $p_cnt; $i++) { 
$title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
$description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
$rssurl = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
$rsscat = $xml->channel->item[$i]->category;
$rsscreator = $xml->channel->item[$i]->dc;
if($title == ""){
$tle = 'بدون عنوان';
} else {
$tle = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
}
echo '<tr>
<td class="MTForumrowtitle"><a href="'.$rssurl.'">'.$tle.'</a></td>
<td class="MTForumrowtitle" style="width:186px">'.$rsscat.'</td>
<td class="MTForumrowtitle" style="width:186px">'.$rsscreator.'</td>
</tr>';
} 

}

echo "        </tr>
    </table>
</div>";

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple XML - Dealing With Colons In Nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186107/simple-xml-dealing-with-colons-in-nodes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dc` is a [Dublin Core Metadata Initiative : DCMI](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-namespace/) namespace; in order to access its child elements you need to do something like this:

```
    for ($xml->channel->item as $item) 
    {
       $dc = $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
```

and then you can read the `creator` element like this:

```
       $rsscreator = $dc->creator;
```

Comment: Kudos for using the actual namespace and not the prefix :-)

Comment: may i ask you please to integrate your code with my code? i couldnt do that, thanks

Comment: How can i insert your code in my loop @Hatef ? may i ask you to integrate your code with mine? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is one worked for me:

```
$credit = $item->children('dc', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
echo("creator -".$credit."<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dc = $articulos->channel->item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
// echoes the content of the <dc:creator/> tag
echo $dc->creator;
```

Comment: This looks like the accepted answer, posted more than two years ago. If there is anything new to add, you should add some explanation to your answer