# Not getting all data from xml file after parsing

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse XML to php array/object so I can work with the data.

I have tryed:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578969/14794618](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431742/14794618

But I can't get all data.

This is my code:

```
<?php

function getInfoByICO(string $ico)
{
    $areApiUrl = 'https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?ico=';
    $response= file_get_contents($areApiUrl . $ico);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    var_dump($xml);
}
getInfoByICO('27074358');
?>
```

The API I'm trying to get data from is [here](https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?ico=27074358)

The XML so you don't have to open that URL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<are:Ares_odpovedi xmlns:are="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_basic/v_1.0.3" xmlns:D="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_datatypes/v_1.0.3" xmlns:U="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/uvis_datatypes/v_1.0.3" odpoved_datum_cas="2022-01-05T12:43:02" odpoved_pocet="1" odpoved_typ="Basic" vystup_format="XML" xslt="klient" validation_XSLT="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_odpovedi.xsl" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_basic/v_1.0.3 http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_basic/v_1.0.3/ares_answer_basic_v_1.0.3.xsd" Id="ares">
<are:Odpoved>
<D:PID>0</D:PID>
<D:VH>
<D:K>1</D:K>
</D:VH>
<D:PZA>1</D:PZA>
<D:UVOD>
<D:ND>Výpis z dat Registru ARES - aktuální stav ke dni 2022-01-04</D:ND>
<D:ADB>2022-01-04</D:ADB>
<D:DVY>2022-01-05</D:DVY>
<D:CAS>12:43:01</D:CAS>
<D:Typ_odkazu>0</D:Typ_odkazu>
</D:UVOD>
<D:VBAS>
<D:ICO zdroj="OR">27074358</D:ICO>
<D:DIC zdroj="DPH">CZ27074358</D:DIC>
<D:OF zdroj="OR">Asseco Central Europe, a.s.</D:OF>
<D:DV>2003-08-06</D:DV>
<D:PF zdroj="OR">
<D:KPF>121</D:KPF>
<D:NPF>Akciová společnost</D:NPF>
</D:PF>
<D:AD zdroj="ARES">
<D:UC>Budějovická 778</D:UC>
<D:PB>14000 Praha</D:PB>
</D:AD>
<D:AA zdroj="ARES">
<D:IDA>211408409</D:IDA>
<D:KS>203</D:KS>
<D:NS>Česká republika</D:NS>
<D:N>Praha</D:N>
<D:NCO>Michle</D:NCO>
<D:NMC>Praha 4</D:NMC>
<D:NU>Budějovická</D:NU>
<D:CD>778</D:CD>
<D:TCD>1</D:TCD>
<D:CO>3a</D:CO>
<D:PSC>14000</D:PSC>
<D:AU>
<U:KOL>19</U:KOL>
<U:KK>19</U:KK>
<U:KOK>3100</U:KOK>
<U:KO>554782</U:KO>
<U:KPO>43</U:KPO>
<U:KN>43</U:KN>
<U:KCO>490130</U:KCO>
<U:KMC>500119</U:KMC>
<U:PSC>14000</U:PSC>
<U:KUL>444375</U:KUL>
<U:CD>778</U:CD>
<U:TCD>1</U:TCD>
<U:CO>3</U:CO>
<U:PCO>a</U:PCO>
<U:KA>41405609</U:KA>
<U:KOB>21770794</U:KOB>
</D:AU>
</D:AA>
<D:PSU>NAAANANNNNANNNNNNNNNNNNNANNNNN</D:PSU>
<D:ROR>
<D:SZ>
<D:SD>
<D:K>1</D:K>
<D:T>Městský soud v Praze</D:T>
</D:SD>
<D:OV>B 8525</D:OV>
</D:SZ>
<D:SOR>
<D:SSU>Aktivní</D:SSU>
<D:KKZ>
<D:K>0</D:K>
</D:KKZ>
<D:VY>
<D:K>0</D:K>
</D:VY>
<D:ZAM>
<D:K>0</D:K>
</D:ZAM>
<D:LI>
<D:K>0</D:K>
</D:LI>
</D:SOR>
</D:ROR>
<D:RRZ>
<D:ZU>
<D:KZU>310004</D:KZU>
<D:NZU>Úřad městské části Praha 4</D:NZU>
</D:ZU>
<D:FU>
<D:KFU>4</D:KFU>
<D:NFU>Praha 4</D:NFU>
</D:FU>
</D:RRZ>
<D:KPP zdroj="RES">250 - 499 zaměstnanců</D:KPP>
<D:Nace>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">181</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">261</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">26300</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">43210</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">461</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">46900</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">47</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">52290</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">5590</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">61</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">620</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">63</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">6820</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">69200</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">711</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">7120</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">73120</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">73200</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">74</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">74300</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">80</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">80200</D:NACE>
<D:NACE zdroj="RES">8559</D:NACE>
</D:Nace>
<D:PPI>
<D:PP zdroj="OR">
<D:T>
Činnost účetních poradců, vedení účetnictví, vedení daňové evidence
</D:T>
<D:T>
pronájem nemovitostí, bytů a nebytových prostor s poskytováním jen základních služeb zajišťujících řádný provoz nemovitostí, bytů a nebytových prostor
</D:T>
<D:T>
Montáž, opravy, revize a zkoušky elektrických zařízení
</D:T>
<D:T>
Výroba, obchod a služby neuvedené v přílohách 1 až 3 živnostenského zákona
</D:T>
<D:T>
Výroba, instalace, opravy elektrických strojů a přístrojů, elektronických a telekomunikačních zařízení
</D:T>
<D:T>
poskytování technických služeb k ochraně majetku a osob
</D:T>
</D:PP>
<D:PP zdroj="RZP">
<D:T>Výroba, instalace, opravy elektrických strojů a přístrojů, elektronických a telekomunikačních zařízení</D:T>
<D:T>Poskytování technických služeb k ochraně majetku a osob</D:T>
<D:T>Výroba, obchod a služby neuvedené v přílohách 1 až 3 živnostenského zákona</D:T>
<D:T>Činnost účetních poradců, vedení účetnictví, vedení daňové evidence</D:T>
<D:T>Montáž, opravy, revize a zkoušky elektrických zařízení</D:T>
</D:PP>
</D:PPI>
<D:Obory_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01014</D:K>
<D:T>Vydavatelské činnosti, polygrafická výroba, knihařské a kopírovací práce</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01047</D:K>
<D:T>Zprostředkování obchodu a služeb</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01048</D:K>
<D:T>Velkoobchod a maloobchod</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01052</D:K>
<D:T>Skladování, balení zboží, manipulace s nákladem a technické činnosti v dopravě</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01053</D:K>
<D:T>Zasilatelství a zastupování v celním řízení</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01055</D:K>
<D:T>Ubytovací služby</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01056</D:K>
<D:T>Poskytování software, poradenství v oblasti informačních technologií, zpracování dat, hostingové a související činnosti a webové portály</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01060</D:K>
<D:T>Poradenská a konzultační činnost, zpracování odborných studií a posudků</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01062</D:K>
<D:T>Příprava a vypracování technických návrhů, grafické a kresličské práce</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01063</D:K>
<D:T>Projektování elektrických zařízení</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01064</D:K>
<D:T>Výzkum a vývoj v oblasti přírodních a technických věd nebo společenských věd</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01065</D:K>
<D:T>Testování, měření, analýzy a kontroly</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01066</D:K>
<D:T>Reklamní činnost, marketing, mediální zastoupení</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01070</D:K>
<D:T>Služby v oblasti administrativní správy a služby organizačně hospodářské povahy</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01072</D:K>
<D:T>Mimoškolní výchova a vzdělávání, pořádání kurzů, školení, včetně lektorské činnosti</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:Obor_cinnosti>
<D:K>Z01080</D:K>
<D:T>Výroba, obchod a služby jinde nezařazené</D:T>
</D:Obor_cinnosti>
</D:Obory_cinnosti>
</D:VBAS>
</are:Odpoved>
</are:Ares_odpovedi>
```

I only get this with my code:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["odpoved_datum_cas"]=>
    string(19) "2022-01-05T12:51:08"
    ["odpoved_pocet"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["odpoved_typ"]=>
    string(5) "Basic"
    ["vystup_format"]=>
    string(3) "XML"
    ["xslt"]=>
    string(6) "klient"
    ["validation_XSLT"]=>
    string(66) "http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_odpovedi.xsl"
    ["Id"]=>
    string(4) "ares"
  }
}
```

But there is a lot missing (everything I get is useless to me)

**Edit:**
Also tried:

`$xml->children()` - does not work, outputs the same thing but not wrapped in object

`$xml->children()->children()` - does not work, outputs empty object

Don't know how to make it work properly:
[this suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186117/17840479) - I can't really figure out how to make it work for me.

Comment: Your `var_dump` only dumps the exact element in the variable (which is the first element, which has those attributes that you're seeing in the dump). You have to actually *use* the objects methods to see the rest. see `$xml->children()` for instance. Read the SimpleXMLElement documentation for a full overview of all the features.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple XML - Dealing With Colons In Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186107/simple-xml-dealing-with-colons-in-nodes)

Comment: lots of namespaces to deal with here

Comment: Using children() doesn’t work, I just get an empty object.

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestions